# boost asio async_read no call the callback

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, tcp, network-programming, boost-asio

I am trying to read big amount of data asynchronously.

With "other" libraries in synchronous mode I need call read some times by chunks because tcp is a stream and the window size is limited.

So I think that need do it with `async_read` from boost asio, but the callback is called for short data (eg: 1024), when the amount of data grow(eg: `max_length = 80000 > 65536`) the callback is not called, so what am I doing wrong?, this is an example the produce my problem:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/read.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

namespace ba = boost::asio;

enum { max_length = 1024 };

int main() {
  ba::io_service io_service;
  ba::ip::tcp::socket sk(io_service);
  ba::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
  ba::connect(sk,
              resolver.resolve(ba::ip::tcp::resolver::query{ba::ip::tcp::v4(),
                                                            "127.0.0.1",
                                                            "8881"}));
  char request[max_length];
  ba::async_read(sk,
                 ba::buffer(request, max_length),
                 [](const boost::system::error_code& err, std::size_t){
    if (!err) {
      std::printf("Callback without error!\n");
    } else {
      std::fprintf(stderr, "Callback with error!\n");
    }
  });
  io_service.run_one();

  // wait the transtition in the async thread.
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{1000});
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If you don't know the size of data that you read or write, you can use boost::asio::streambuf, as a container for your data, then you can create istreams or ostream objects and manipulate the underlying streambuf with them very easy. The advantage of using streambuf, is that it will allocate memory automatically when it needs and will also work more efficiently with disks.

Answer (score 3):

The overload for `async_read` you are using is equivalent to:

```
boost::asio::async_read(
    s, buffers,
    boost::asio::transfer_all(), // this is the completion condition
    handler);
```

The `transfer_all` condition means it will only complete when either the buffer is full, or the connection ends.

So if you don't see the callback being invoked, it's probably because the connection was not closed (from the other side), or the buffer is not yet full.

There are other completion conditions, such as `transfer_at_least` and `transfer_exactly`, and also other `async_read*` functions. Without knowing exactly what you want to do, it's hard to recommend which one you need.

You can also invoke the socket's `async_read_some` method instead, it behaves more like traditional low level BSD sockets (the callback is invoked as soon as something is read.)

Comment: I solve the problem by using the member function async_read_some from boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket, but I not undertand why you sugestions not work for my, I tryed with boost::asio::transfer_exactly(), boost::asio::transfer_all(), boost::asio::transfer_at_least().
Some body can explain this isue? What I making wrong?

Comment: How many bytes are actually being sent? How many bytes did you use for `transfer_at_least`? If only one byte is sent, and you ask to receive at least 2, you will still never see the callback being invoked (until the connection ends). There's nothing wrong with using the `async_read_some` method if that's the logic you need; it should be equivalent to using `transfer_at_least(1)`.

Comment: Ok, if the server send 1 byte and I try read 2 bytes, the original implementation should call the callback with an error notification?

original implementation:
ba::async_read(sk,
                          ba::buffer(request, max_length),
                          [](const boost::system::error_code& err, std::size_t){});

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Antony Polukhin from https://plus.google.com/communities/106814259809358442744 24 de feb. de 2015.

Try to use io_service.run(); instead of io_service.run_one();. Also, fix the err check:

```
// (err == boost::asio::error::eof) - Connection
// closed cleanly by peer
if (!err || err == ba::error::eof) {
  std::printf("Callback without error!\n");
} else {
  std::fprintf(stderr, "Callback with error!\n");
}
```

Also it looks like you do not need the following line:
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{1000});

Short description:
async_read operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's async_read_some function. When calling io_service.run_one() you request to execute only one call - the first call to the async_read_some (other calls will be skipped). That's why you receive only 65535 bytes and the callback is not called (callback will be called after the last async_read_some finishes).

io_service.run() and io_service.run_one() run the operations in current thread and block the thread untill the operation is completed, so there's no need to call sleep.﻿

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `io_service` (lately known as `io_context`) is restarted and running after `async_read` call:

```
io_service.restart();
io_service.run_one();
```